Spring Batch - Using Custom Classifier how to create two more files
I'm using Spring Batch XML for my project and have below requirement to fullfill. My task is

connect Sybase DB, read all records from the table
Based on clientId (there are 10 different clientId), segregate the records. I can use Classifier interface to do that and write data to 10 different files.
Also I need to create Audit file for each file. Here audit file is custom XML file in that I need to mentioned recordCount, FileName and its size etc
Then Last I need to create one more txt file to let them know about the Business Date
How can we come to know which Writer got how many records etc

How Can I achieve the highlighted points using Spring Batch or some other things?
